# Yahoo pipes: fetch page

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I want to use a part of the web page in an open sorce digital signage software.

Can anybody tell me how can I use yahoo pipes: fetch page to get part of the web page that I want in a very simple way. It seems to complex to me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you select the module on the left side a description will appear underneath with a link to an example that uses it. If that's not enough maybe tell us where specifically you're confused.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Pipes has a module called "Fetch Page" and all you have to do is fill in the URL of the page.

However would not advise using pipes for this application because..

1. The owner of a website can easily block Yahoo Pipes.
2. Yahoo has a bad habit of changing the way the Pipes service works.
3. A Yahoo Pipe can only be called 200 times in ten minutes.

Suggest using cURL to fetch your required information.